# How can I reduce power usage in a location-based Android application?

Tags: android

How can I reduce the power usage in my application?  What code can I use to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to reduce the power used when trying to get location information.

1. Use the [last known location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) instead of trying to determine the current location.

   ```
   // Get a Location Manager
   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   // Try to get the last GPS based location
   Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

   // Fall back to cell tower based location if no prior GPS location
   if (l == null) {
       l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
   }
   ```
2. Use a less expensive location provider.  You can pick [LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) directly or specify the [criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) you care about and let Android tell you which location provider to use.

   ```
   // Select the criteria you care about
   Criteria c = new Criteria();
   c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
   c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

   // Let the system tell you what provider you should use for your criteria
   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   String p = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);

   // Call other Location Manager functions using the above provider...
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much  i am implemented

Comment: in my application battery usage in 50% its suitable  another way of battery usage and memory usage